# How do backend as a service providers provide data integrity?

Tags: backend, paas

Mobile backend-as-a-service providers (MBaaS) such as KiiCloud (http://developer.kii.com), Parse (http://parse.com), Applicasa (http://www.applicasa.com), Kinvey (http://www.kinvey.com), etc. provide data storage on the cloud. How do they make sure stored objects are consistent, not duplicated, etc. Is stored data eventually consistent because it's cloud based?

Best regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: One another Player of Backend-as-a-Service App42 (api.shephertz.com) which  data store on the cloud using NoSQL Storage like MongoDB.If we are talking about data consistent than NoSQL Storage maintain every document has a unique Id.So  no chance of  inconsistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the new BaaS providers utilize one of the off-the-shelf NoSQL solutions like MongoDB.  As such, they're able to focus on performance tuning more so than the actual underlying mechanics of data sync and replication.

Here's a link to a post from Kinvey's CTO on Quora:
http://www.quora.com/Backend-as-a-Service/How-do-backend-as-a-service-providers-Stackmob-Parse-Kinvey-Kii-Cloud-UserGrid-maintain-data-integrity